# moment.js - Convert short month to long month?

Tags: momentjs

Given the following short month:

```
var shortMonth = 'Jan';
```

How can I convert it to the long month format `January` using moment.js?

`moment().format('MMMM');` is what gives the long month format of the **current** month, but I can't seem to find a way to convert a short month to a long month.

Something like `moment().format(shortMonth,'MMMM');` for example doesn't work.

Any idea how to get it to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
moment('Jan', 'MMM').format('MMMM')
```

Comment: Works flawlessly - Thanks for showing how it's done!